# Application crashes; 'Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion' returning 10.9.2

Tags: macos, crash

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and I've got its icon in my dock. However, when I try to start it by clicking the icon, it immediately crashes with the following error (in Console);

```
08/04/15 16:57:11,828 Sublime Text[1397]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.2 instead of 10.10.2. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
08/04/15 16:57:11,829 Sublime Text[1397]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8986ed9b ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 113
08/04/15 16:57:11,829 Sublime Text[1397]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f9c9c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
08/04/15 16:57:11,829 Sublime Text[1397]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f9c9b26 dispatch_once_f + 117
08/04/15 16:57:11,829 Sublime Text[1397]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff898173ca _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 987
08/04/15 16:57:11,830 Sublime Text[1397]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff89816fb7 Gestalt + 144
08/04/15 16:57:11,830 Sublime Text[1397]: 5   Sublime Text                        0x000000010863519b _Z10os_versionv + 29
08/04/15 16:57:11,830 Sublime Text[1397]: 6   Sublime Text                        0x0000000108613397 _Z16px_create_windowP23px_window_event_handlerP11px_window_tddPKcj + 605
```

It seems to indicate an issue related to OSX Yosemite vs OSX Mavericks. The documentation I find online w.r.t. this problem seems to concern a wide variety of programs, but none of it consistently. There's a [discussion on the Apple discussion boards](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6686435), but it holds no answers.

For my specific case, the weird thing is that I can in fact start the Sublime binary (i.e. via the Terminal). This seems to indicate that something is going wrong in the `.app` wrapper

What could I try?

EDIT: I'm running Yosemite 10.10.2, and have upgraded from Mavericks. However, this has not been broken from the get-go, and Sublime Text 3 is the only application I'm experiencing this with.

Comment: Are you running Yosemite or Mavericks?

Comment: Yosemite. I should've added that.

Comment: Have you tried trashing sublime's preferences in your library? Does it happen in a 2nd user? Are you using a beta-build or any plugins?

Comment: Deleting the preferences does indeed fix it. I suppose I'll have to manually migrate my preferences, then..

Comment: Same thing happens to me crashing iterm.